# Condition upon URL in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

My URL is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/notifications/2`. I am trying to put condition in View(blade) file like below.

```
@if (request()->routeIs('notifications/*'))
//some code
@endif
```

But it is not working.

How can I do that ?

Comment: Try with `request()->is('notifications/*');`; I've never seen this `routeIs()` method... Where in the documentation did you see that?

Answer (score 1):

You need :

```
@if (request()->segment(0) == 'notifications')
   //some code
@endif
```

**Segments** are an array that starts at index 0. In the above url, `segment(0)` will be `notifications` and `segment(1)` will be `2`